# Tennis match problem

Tags: probability, expected-value, variance

Two equally strong tennis players play against each other until one of them wins three matches in a row.  What is the coefficient of variation of the number of matches played.

Can we assume that the $p$ of winning three in a row is $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3$,and not winning is $1-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3$, and treat this as geometric .

So the mean becomes $\frac{1-p}{p}$?

Unable to solve further

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can solve through geometric distribution but you have to look into how it works for n successes or failures in a row.

Here we are seeking 3 consecutive successes (player 1 wins 3) or 3 consecutive failures (player 1 loses 3) with each success chance being $\frac{1}{2}$ and each failure chance also being $\frac{1}{2}$. Assume player 1 winning a match is success and player 1 losing (player 2 winning) is a failure. We are assuming that outcome of a match is independent of the previous outcomes. It is similar to a fair coin being tossed and you are seeking 3 consecutive heads or tails.

Expected number of matches before you get 3 consecutive successes will be  $ \frac{1 + \frac{1}{2} + (\frac{1}{2})^2}{(\frac{1}{2})^3}$. This translates to 14.

It is going to be the same for 3 consecutive failures (other player winning).

But as we are fine with either 3 consecutive successes or 3 consecutive failures, it will translate to 7 matches.

You may also want to read through Markov chain.

Comment: How did you get the formula 1+1/2+ (1/2)^2.?

Comment: How do we find the variance .?

Comment: Take an example of number of tosses required to get 2 consecutive heads is n - if you get T in the first toss (with probability 1/2), you will need 1 additional toss (n+1). If you get {HT} (with probability 1/4), you will now need 2 additional tosses (n+2). If you get {HH} (with probability 1/4), the number of tosses will be 2. So the number of tosses, n = (n+1)/2 + (n+2)/4 + 2/4. It translates to $(1+p)/p^2$ and gives you n = 6. For 3H or 3T, it will be $(1+p+p^2)/p^3$. You can extend the same to N consecutive heads or tails.

Comment: How do we get the variance ?

Comment: Are you able to get variance for first head or first tail appearance?

Comment: First head is geometric right.? Where mean will be 2 and variance 4

Comment: Here there is a change we get 14 and then take half of that to be mean trials..

Comment: For 2 heads in a row, the variance will equate to $\frac{1}{p^4}+\frac{2}{p^3}-\frac{2}{p^2}-\frac{1}{p}$ or to generalize for n heads in a row, it should be $2^{2N+1}-N.2^N-2$. Similarly for 3 tails in a row. Otherwise you can come up with $Var (X_N) = E(X_N^2) - E(X_N)^2$.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on the formula.? I used your method the variance for the tennis match comes to 102 using your method but the answer says 22...

Comment: I think in the tennis match problem it has to be half of 14 to get 7, but how do you adjust the variance since that will also be higher...